# Issue setting up subscription with GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-subscriptions

Good day:

I"m trying to setup my graphql server for a subscription. This is my schema.js

```
const ChatCreatedSubscription = new GraphQLObjectType({ 
  name: "ChatCreated",
  fields: () => ({
    chatCreated: {  
          subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator(CONSTANTS.Websocket.CHANNEL_CONNECT_CUSTOMER) 
    }
  })
});

const ChatConnectedSubscription = {
  chatConnected: {
      subscribe: withFilter(
         (_, args) => pubsub.asyncIterator(`${args.id}`),
         (payload, variables) => payload.chatConnect.id === variables.id,
      )
  }
}




const subscriptionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Subscription",
  fields: () => ({
    chatCreated: ChatCreatedSubscription,
    chatConnected: ChatConnectedSubscription
  })
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  subscription: subscriptionType
});
```

However, I'm getting this error when I try to run my subscription server:

```
ERROR introspecting schema:  [
  {
    "message": "The type of Subscription.chatCreated must be Output Type but got: undefined."
  },
  {
    "message": "The type of Subscription.chatConnected must be Output Type but got: undefined."
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

A field definition is an object that includes these properties: `type`, `args`, `description`, `deprecationReason` and `resolve`. All these properties are optional except `type`. Each field in your field map must be an object like this -- you cannot just set the field to a type like you're doing.

Incorrect:

```
const subscriptionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Subscription",
  fields: () => ({
    chatCreated: ChatCreatedSubscription,
    chatConnected: ChatConnectedSubscription
  })
});
```

Correct:

```
const subscriptionType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Subscription",
  fields: () => ({
    chatCreated: {
      type: ChatCreatedSubscription,
    },
    chatConnected: {
      type: ChatConnectedSubscription,
    },
  })
});
```

Check [the docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype) for additional examples.

Comment: @tried that but, getting: `Schema must contain unique named types but contains multiple types named "undefined"`

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to that error, but `ChatConnectedSubscription` is also a plain object and not an instance of GraphQLObjectType.

Comment: You'll need to specify types for all fields in your schema, i.e. `chatCreated`, `chatConnected` and so on.